# call jquery function from window.open()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the problem. I need load template from file and write it to new `window.document`.

```
var newWindow = $window.open();
newWindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
newWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
newWindow.document.write('<div id="element">test</div>');
newWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
$(printWindow.document).load('template.html  #element')
newWindow.document.close();
```

And `$(printWindow.document).load('template.html  #element')` doesn't work.

How do I implement this?

Comment: Why not open a new page which has that content already in it? That way you won't be running the risk of updating the content across windows being blocked by the browser security policy.

Comment: Or, why won't you load the template before opening the window? Also, what is `printWindow` ?

Comment: sorry. printwindow is old var name

Comment: I need load template because it will be filled by specific dynamic data

Comment: Load the template in the main window and have it write to the popup.

Comment: @Shilly, I use this solution now, but in my opinion is more clear to load directly to this new window

Comment: Do you understand that you're running into window privacy and security settings? If you prepare the entire node structure you want on the parent window, you can insert it into the popup window without issues. So the solution is to actually .get() the tempalte on the aprent and then isnert those nodes into the popup. Remmeber, the popup doesn't ahve control over the parent, the parent has control over the popup.

Comment: @Shilly I just want to print document without all page structure. Just only text of document with existing template, which I load. It's not popup.

Comment: We had to solve the exact same problem you are trying to solve and have told you how we did it, what the issues are and why we didn't just $().load() . Anything else?